# shell_exec and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, shell-exec

I have a problem with my path. I am on windows, I want to use shell_exec to create pdf files.

This one doesn't work.

```
$cmd = 'wkhtmltopdf --cookie PHPSESSID q76abf3752tvttqds9qid1ca54 --print-media-type "http://localhost/al60/index.php?id=46&contr=dealer&event=loanrequests_details" "C:\Users\Bapt\AppData\Local\Temp/download_pdf_1381962017.pdf"';
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

This one works.

```
$cmd = '"c:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --cookie PHPSESSID q76abf3752tvttqds9qid1ca54 --print-media-type "http://localhost/al60/index.php?id=46&contr=dealer&event=loanrequests_details" "C:\Users\Bapt\AppData\Local\Temp/download_pdf_1381962017.pdf"';
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I don't want to set the path of my executable, because it will have to run on other computers (including linux), I just want to use the name and let the OS resolve the path as it does in a command line. I have my path environment set up correctly for all user in my windows machine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the second code you surrounded it with quotation marks, in the first you didn't could that be it?

Comment: nope, I also tought of that and tried with "wkhtmltopdf" and "wkhtmltopdf.exe" also and it didn't work. On Linux, I know that I have to set the path for the user that runs apache, but on windows, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: why not just query $_SERVER ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]? and make your judgement by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after thinking, I decided to echo the path

```
$output = shell_exec('echo %Path%');
$logger->log($output);
```

And the path to `wkhtmltopdf`, that I have added was not there. So I restarted apache, and it didn't work, so I restarted windows and it worked.

The good old restart :)